# DownloadFileAsync with webclient issue

Tags: asp.net, ftp

I am trying to download file from FTP using Webclient DownloadFileAsync method. i have used below code

```
private  bool DownloadFileFromFtp()
{
    try
    {

        MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient();

        Uri ftpurl = new Uri("ftp://MyFtpserver/Filename.pdf");
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Userid", "mypassword");
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;

        client.DownloadDataCompleted += Client_DownloadDataCompleted;

        client.DownloadFileAsync(ftpurl, @"D:\RTP\Filename.pdf");
        return true;
    }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
    lbldatareceived.Text = bytesIn + "/" + totalBytes;
    lblPercentage.Text = percentage+"%";
    FileProgress.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("width", Convert.ToString(percentage) + '%');
    FileProgress.Attributes.Add("aria-valuenow", Convert.ToString(percentage));
}
private void Client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

When I run this code file download gets starts and browser start loading. How can I download files without loading a browser?

Comment: Please don't label C# code as if it's Javascript code that can be run in the browser.

Comment: HTTP is request/response. By the time the browser is showing your empty progress bar, the response is over. As a server, you don't get (using plain HTTP) to send further updates such as applying new CSS or attributes.